# Exchange - limit enrollment of ActiveSync devices

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell, activesync

Is it possible to modify an ActiveSync policy to prevent a user from having more than one (or any specified number of) device(s) enrolled simultaneously?  What would be the Powershell script to do so?

Environment: Exchange 2010 Enterprise SP2 (soon to be SP3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum number of ActiveSync devices allowed is controlled by the throttling policy. You can find out which throttling policy is assigned to a mailbox with Get-Mailbox and then change that policy with [Set-ThrottlingPolicy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298094%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx).